# ¿Como puedo trabajar con cookies con JS o jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cookies

Necesito crear, leer y eliminar cookies desde el lado del cliente, para ello necesito usar javascript o jQuery pero no se como manipular las cookies desde acá, existe algun framework que ayude con este tema o bien debo construir mis propias funciones en javascript para crear, leer y eliminar una cookie?

Answer (score 1):

te dejo este link, espero te sirva
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Aquí puedes ver el código:

```
 //función para crear la cookie
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}

//función para leer la cookie
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}

//función para validar una cookie

function checkCookie() {
    var user = getCookie("username");
    if (user != "") {
        alert("Welcome again " + user);
    } else {
        user = prompt("Please enter your name:", "");
        if (user != "" && user != null) {
            setCookie("username", user, 365);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: gracias por el apoyo, pero se pide que las respuestas sean una mezcla de explicación y código, ya que que pasa si ese link después deja de ser funcional; otras personas que tengan la misma duda no van a poder consultarlo, al mismo tiempo te comento tu respuesta parece mas un comentario y como tal es reportada como de baja calidad

Comment: bien, agregaré el código