# Borrar localstorage JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5, local-storage

Tengo una variable guardada en el localStorage, pero lo que necesito es que dicha variable se borre automáticamente después de 4 horas, como lo haría?
La asigno así:

```
localStorage.setItem('token',token);
```

¿Cómo hacer para que ese token se borre a las 4 horas?

Pd: No hago sessionStorage porque no quiero que se borre cada vez que el usuario cierre el navegador.

Comment: No se puede a menos que tengas tu página abierta durante estas 4 horas. La información guardada en localStorage no tiene fecha de caducidad

Comment: Pero que has intentado? a tu objeto token agregale la propiedad de caducidad, y deja un web worker que verfique la caducidad de ese valor.

Comment: Amigos soy muy novato en esto del frontend, entonces no es q haya intentado muchas soluciones, voy a probar la opción de Miguel e investigar sobre lo q el me indica para ver q ocurre, de todos modos desde el servidor el token es válido por 4 horas, por ello necesito que la localstorage se borre cuando transcurra ese tiempo, ya les iré contando

Answer (score 1):

La respuesta original es de [enStackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30730835/2097224) pero hace tiempo que lo modifique un poco a mis necesidades.

---

**Asignar clave, valor y caducidad:**

```
setStorage = ( key, value = '', expires ) => {

  if ( expires === undefined || expires === null ) {

    // Por defecto: segundos por 1 día
    expires = ( 24 * 60 * 60 );
  }
  else {        

    expires = Math.abs( expires );
  }

  let now      = Date.now();
  let schedule = now + expires * 1000;

  try {

    localStorage.setItem( key, schedule );
  }
  catch ( e ) {

    console.log( 'setStorage: Error setting key [' + key + '] in localStorage: ' + JSON.stringify( e ) );
    return false;
  }

  return true;
};
```

Ejemplo de uso: `setStorage( 'clave', 'valor', 60 ); // 1 Minuto`

---

**Recibir valor:**

```
getStorage = key => {

  let now       = Date.now();
  let expiresIn = localStorage.getItem( key );

  if ( expiresIn === undefined || expiresIn === null ) {
    expiresIn = '0';
  }

  // Si esta caducado eliminamos
  if ( parseInt( expiresIn ) < now ) {

    removeStorage( key );
    return null;
  }
  else {
    try {

      return localStorage.getItem( key );
    }
    catch ( e ) {

      console.log( 'getStorage: Error reading key [' + key + '] from localStorage: ' + JSON.stringify( e ) );

      return null;
    }
  }
};
```

Ejemplo de uso: `getStorage( 'clave' )`;

---

**Eliminar:**

```
removeStorage = key => {

  try {

    localStorage.removeItem( key );
  }
  catch ( e ) {

    console.log( 'removeStorage: Error removing key [' + key + '] from localStorage: ' + JSON.stringify( e ) );
    return false;
  }

  return true;
};
```

Ejemplo de uso: `removeStorage( 'clave' );`

Comment: aun falta un detalle la clave se debe remover automaticamente, sin interaccion del usuario,

Comment: @MiguelZarate - No entiendo exactamente `remover automaticamente`... en cuando quiera leer el valor con `getStorage()` lo remueve si esta expirado... y si lo quiere hacer "automaticamente"  podría hacer un `setInterval()`.. cada minuto.. cada hora... etc...

Comment: eso ultimo es lo que falta, una funcion que este verificando la caducidad del token, con eso ya completas tu respuesta.

Comment: @MiguelZarate - No sé si me he explicado mal o lo entiendo mal... a la variable se asigna un `timestamp` y en el momento cuando se lea esa variable y esté caducado se borra... no entiendo porque tiene que ser borrado antes? Y si sale del navegador no será posible automáticamente no? Así que lo único que se me ocurre es poner `getStorage()` dentro de un `setInterval()` y compruebe cada cierto tiempo... pero la verdad no lo veo mucho sentido que sea borrado antes... pero si es eso lo que quiere el OP actualizaré la respuesta... Gracias y saludos!

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage.removeItem('token');`

Para calcular el tiempo que ha pasado puedes tener otra variable en `localStorage` que indique en qué momento se guardó. Y así, solo tienes que consultar esa otra variable, si han pasado 4 horas o más. Lo borras.

¿Es lo que querías?

Answer (score 0):

LocalStorage no proporciona, un método de tiempo expiración de almacenamiento.

Si necesitar almacenar algo con tiempo de expiración podrías usar cookies, estas si proporcionan tiempo de expiración, abajo te dejo un link de un post en SO de como usarlas.

[¿Como puedo trabajar con cookies con JS o jQuery?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/177963/como-puedo-trabajar-con-cookies-con-js-o-jquery)

Pero debes tener en cuenta otras cosas como el tamaño y demás.
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

También, si quieres generar un método propio para usar LocalStorage, podrías generar un objeto que contenga valor, y fecha de generación, y cuando vas a consultarla podrías verificar la fecha.