# Como evitar que una ventana modal se muestre cada vez que se refresque la pagina

Tags: javascript, modal

Estoy en la creación de una ventana modal pero lo único que quiero es que la ventana solo se muestre al abrir la pagina, la pagina tiene diferentes funcionalidades que implica refrescarla pero cuando se refresca la pagina automáticamente la ventana se vuelve a mostrar.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myModal').modal("show");
        })
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    ...
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que no quiero deshabilitar que las paginas se refresquen lo que quiero es que la ventana modal se vuelve a mostrar cada vez que esta se refresque solo que se muestre por única vez

Comment: ya intentaste usando cookies?

Comment: @RuslanLópez No he usado cookies, es posible hacerlo ? Como ?

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/177963/como-puedo-trabajar-con-cookies-con-js-o-jquery

Comment: @RuslanLópez La pregunta no tiene una buena valoración y no se entiende muy bien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega una comprobación con localStorage. Si la llave `mostrarModal` no existe entonces que se cree la llave y se muestre el modal. Si ya existe, el modal no se muestra.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     // si no hay llave con nombre `mostrarModal`
     // crear la llave y mostrar el modal
     if(!window.localStorage.getItem("mostrarModal")){
           
        window.localStorage.setItem("mostrarModal","no");
               
        $('#myModal').modal("show");
      }
                
     })
```

**Actualización**

Para que la llave se elimine al cerrar el navegador se puede usar `sessionStorage` en lugar de `localStorage`

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     // si no hay llave con nombre `mostraModal`
     // crear la llave y mostrar el modal
     if(!window.sessionStorage.getItem("mostrarModal")){
           
        window.sessionStorage.setItem("mostrarModal","no");
               
        $('#myModal').modal("show");
      }
                
     })
```

Comment: Esto no soluciono mi problema, se sigue mostrando la ventana modal después de refrescarse la pagina, adicional a lo que me comentas en la respuesta hay que agregar algo ?

Comment: Cierto, estaba mal escrito el nombre de la llave. Ya lo corregí. Y no, no hay que agregar nada más, solo es esa validación.

Comment: Funciona perfecto, pero estoy presentando un problema, es que la key queda viva al cerrar el navegador y abrir la ventana nuevamente, existe manera de que la key se elimine al cerrar el navegador ?

Comment: Ya agregué una actualización a la respuesta.

Comment: Excelente respuesta clara y concisa

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza sessionStorage para almacenar una variable para comparar si el modal a sido o no mostrado.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 if(sessionStorage.getItem("mostrarModal")!=null){
    sessionStorage.setItem("mostrarModal",true);
    $('#myModal').modal("show");
 }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Muchas gracias @Lobos, me sirvió tu respuesta. A continuación comparto la documentación que refuerza tu respuesta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[Fuente original pulse aquí!](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: Ten en cuenta que [no todos pueden visualizar correctamente las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976), por lo tanto comparte las partes esenciales de la documentación _como texto_. Lee [answer].